# CSS or JavaScript Conflict - Google Map Won't Display

Tags: javascript, css, conflict

The WordPress theme I am using has built in JavaScript and CSS for Google maps on the contact page. So, I'm guessing there is conflicting code. I can't seem to find where the conflict is when I am trying to use a plugin which also uses Google Maps.

I would really appreciate any help correcting this issue so that this Google Map will display instead of an empty gray box. I tried everything I know to do.

http://boothambuilders.com/service-area/

The plugin works on all other themes I'm using.

Also, this is the only page where the background doesn't display properly. I don't know how it is related to the issue.

Comment: Use Firebug to look for `css`, `cssText`, and `style` in your JavaScript, and of course click on the conflict area in Firebug and look at your CSS.

Comment: Get Firebug, or use the Chrome debugger. And look at the `console` tab, you'll see the Javascript errors there.

Comment: Thank you both. That helped greatly. Chrome Debug said the Google Maps API was being called twice. Finally found where to remove the extra call from the theme by using a scrpit to search all files for mention of Google API URL.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a CSS conflict, you are calling the Google Maps API twice...